# PIL: Where can I find the "exception" class which contains all the exceptions thrown by PILLOW

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

After lots of struggle, I am unable to find any module named `exception` but in the [source code on Github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/2339/files), it has a line something like `from .exceptions import InvalidFileType, PILReadError`. Where is this `exception` module? On the other hand, it throws some exceptions which are builtin to Python but I could not find any specific module like in `requests.exceptions` or some other modules.

I want to catch and deal with some certain exceptions and when I use `Image.open('non existing file')`, it throws an `FileNotFoundError` but the traceback shows no clue of where it came from. Does the Pillow uses exception directly from `Exception` class? If yes, then what is that `from .exeption` in source code?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/8b806e4a2d54d54c8d49329c11a119c034283d6b/PIL/exceptions.py)?

Comment: You're looking at a *pull request*, not the actual Pillow source code.

Comment: The ˋexceptionˋ module is added by the exact same pull request you have linked.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So there is no such thing as `Exceptions` in PIL?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So nothing like `Exception`? I have to manually Try Catch Everything?

Comment: There are the regular builtin exceptions, e.g. ``FileNotFoundError``, and Pillow specific exceptions, e.g. ``PIL.ImageCms.PyCMSError``. There *currently* is no ``PIL.exception`` module to aggregate exceptions specific to Pillow.

Answer (score 1):

The source you link appears to be to a fork of Pillow.  The ".exceptions" is referring to the definitions in this file https://github.com/jleclanche/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/exceptions.py, which is in the same folder.  There is a `__init__.py` file in this folder, so any .py file in this folder can be imported as a module (provided you run from within this folder or the folder is included in the PYTHONPATH).  These exceptions are not currently part of the PILLOW source head.

To find out more about a particular exception, you can look at all of the attributes for a separate instance of the exception in question.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
d = Exception('This is a base exception from exceptions')
dir(d)
```

And then you can see which attributes the exception object has.  Two useful attributes would be `__doc__` and `__repr__`

Comment: I'm confused why this answer was downvoted.  I'm still new to SO and I'd like to understand why this answer is not useful given the question asked.  I pointed the user to the location of the exception definition (which they asked) and then explained how to get more information/context about exceptions in Python, in general.  Why is this not a useful answer?